# mat-accordion and nested mat-expansion-panel - how to have only one opened?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've got a following structure:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel>(some panel body)</mat-expansion-panel>
  <some-component></some-component>
</mat-accordion>
```

and `some-component`'s template also contains some `mat-expansion-panel`s.

The problem is that expanding the panel which is inside the `some-component` is not causing other panels to collapse.

It seems that I somehow have to specify the accordion to use for those child panels, but cant figure out how.

According to the docs (https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) there is a property for that, but trying this lead me to an error `Can't bind to 'accordion' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-expansion-panel'`.

How can I make only one panel to be expanded at a time?

Demo reproducing the error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lyuqsp

Comment: seems that this is an issue for an old angular (4) that I have here - can't reproduce on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this piece of code and succeeded:

```
if(this.matExpansionPanel.extended) { // usually return false for it catched the state when you clicked the button - when the panel was still closed
    // do something you want
}
else {
    this.matExpansionPanel.toggle();
    // do something you want
}
```

In your case, inside the mat-extension-panel tag, add #youNameIt='matExpansionPanel'.

The matExpansionPanel is the exported type of angular material expansion panel, as mentioned in Angular Material. Back to the .ts script, add @ViewChild('youNameIt') matExpansionPanel /*or any name you want*/ : MatExpansionPanel, then add the above script inside your on click function.

Comment: pls see the demo